# Valgrind Error Due to $User

Tags: ubuntu, valgrind

Got the windows insider build of windows 10, with "bash on ubuntu on windows". (become a windows insider [here](https://insider.windows.com/) and more info on how to get bash on windows [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/04/06/windows-10-build-14316-comes-with-bash-and-more/)) I ran into some problems quickly after installing valgrind:

I run:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
```

Output from valgrind:

```
...
command: ./a.out
error 2 No such file or directory
cannot create shared_mem file /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-12-by-???-on-COENLAPTOP
```

Doing some research I understand that the format for this file is something like

```
/tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-12-by-$USER-on-$HOSTNAME
```

When I `echo $HOSTNAME` I get `COENLAPTOP`, which is the desired response.
When I `echo $USER` I get nothing.

Very peculiar, it seems as if I am not logged in as a user?

Is it possible to change $USER to a valid string? Is this a side-effect of ubuntu on windows?

Comment: USER not set is not a problem: valgrind replaces it with ???, and that should work. Your problem is something else. Maybe try to set vgdb files in another file system by setting TMPDIR or using --vgdb-prefix=... arg.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the Linux subsystem not being able to run memcheck which should be located at `/usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux` I'd be willing to bet that the low level memory calls that valgrind uses are not yet supported by subsystem. We should flag it as an issue on the projects github [page](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues)